# The resut of comparison of the same DateTime value gives 'false'

Tags: c#

```
var expected = DateTime.Now;
var value = expected.ToString();

Assert.AreEqual(expected.Ticks, DateTime.Parse(value).Ticks);
```

*Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<634590535915492841>. Actual:<634590535910000000>.*

Why this is happening?

Comment: Did you stop and think that maybe it's returing `false` because they aren't the same `DateTime` values? You are throwing away information when you call `ToString`. All those zeros at the end tell you that.

Comment: You are right. Sorry - Friday evening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are using the default ToString which doesn't include ticks in the format.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `ToString()` like that, you'll get the default format for the current thread's culture. If you want to round-trip the value, you'll need to use an appropriate format - and indeed there's a format specified [designed specifically for the job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string text = now.ToString("o");
        DateTime parsed;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "o", null,
            DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out parsed))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(parsed == now);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't parse");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Ticks` are equal to 100 nanoseconds.  Given that the restored Ticks value ends in 7 zeroes means that all sub-second details were lost in the `ToString` call.

You will need to use a `ToString` format that yields the precision you need.

```
var expected = DateTime.Now;
var value = expected.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz");

Assert.AreEqual(expected.Ticks, DateTime.Parse(value).Ticks);
```

The important part of the code above is the set of 7 `f`'s.  This yields 7-digit precision on the fractional seconds, which is exactly what was lost on the default `ToString` call.

I built the format string with information from [this MSDN page on DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [The Round-trip ("O", "o") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) in order to preserve all the information contained in DateTime:

string value = expected.ToString("o");